# How does discovering new patterns/recipes/schematics with reverse engineering work?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is there a limit to some crafted items as to how "high" they can go?  Will some not go beyond blue or purple?  Can most items even go up to magenta-quality (super-epic or whatever)?

Does the chance to discover the higher quality recipes change with level or is it some fixed percentage?  (I was burning my low-level materials on some enhancements and it only took me 3 items to get up to purple; lucky?)

Comment: There is an extensive guide on the SWTOR forums: http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=45866

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So, the short version is, **You Got Lucky**.

Here's the long version:

There are two kinds of reverse engineerable items. The first kind is simple. Reverse Engineer the item, learn the pattern for a slightly better version with a higher color-grade quality, up to **Artifact** grade (Purple).  The chance to learn the higher-quality schematic is usually 20%, you can see the chance when hovering over the item. Most crafted item customizations (Armoring, Barrels, Mods, Enhancements, Crystals, Hilts) and consumables follow this system, as do some craftable weapons (but not most).  A crit on crafting one of these results in two of the item rather than one.

The other system is a bit more complicated. Most *equippable* items, when Reverse Engineered, have a chance to teach you a *variant* of the item, which is upgraded. The new recipes name will have one of three prefixes, based on the additional stat that is added to the item:

- **Redoubt** _______________ items will have increased *Defense Rating*.
- **Critical** ___________________ items will have increased *Critical Rating*.
- **Overkill** __________________ items will have increased *Power*.

Unlike critical crafting with base items, a crit on one of these Prototype items will instead be called **Advanced** when they gain an augment slot.

These prototype items, like customizations, can be RE'd *again*, to give you a chance at an **Artifact** grade item. Once again, there are a number of variants - specifically, for each prefix, there are *five* variants that can be learned. These variant items will have *new* prefixes, and add *two additional stats* to the base item. These items will also have the suffix **[Superior]** unless crafted critically (i.e. with an Augment slot), at which point the suffix is changed to **[Masterwork]**.

#### **Overkill** items can be turned into:

- **Vehemence**, which increases *Power* and *Alacrity*.
- **Rampart**, which increases *Power* and *Shield Rating*.
- **Commander's**, which increases *Power* and *Presence*.
- **Expert**, which increases *Power* and *Surge*.
- **Hawkeye**, which increases *Power* and *Accuracy*.

#### **Critical** items can be turned into:

- **Leadership**, which increases *Critical Rating* and *Presence*.
- **Tempest**, which increases *Critical Rating* and *Shield Rating*.
- **Fervor**, which increases *Critical Rating* and *Accuracy*.
- **Endowment**, which increases *Critical Rating* and *Surge*.
- **Supremacy**, which increases *Critical Rating* and *Alacrity*.

**Redoubt** items are a bit of a special case. While 4 variants are known, to date, nobody seems to have been able to craft a +Defense, +Alacrity item. Whether this is a bug (people have invested *a lot* of time into researching this), or simply cosmic levels of bad luck is at this date unknown. That said;

#### **Redoubt** items can be turned into:

- **General's**, which offers *Defense Rating* and *Presence*.
- **Veracity** which increases *Defense Rating* and *Shield Rating*.
- **Anti-Armor** items have added *Defense* and *Surge*.
- **Exactitude** will feature improved *Defense* and *Accuracy*.

The image below provides an example of all the variants that can be crafted of one item:

[image: Example image]

(H/T to the *incredible* research done by **Slaign** over on the [official forums](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=45866) on this one.)

Comment: Is Artifact the [mystic grape](http://www.benjaminmoore.com/en-us/for-your-home/color-gallery?cd=2071-30&col=CP) or the deeper blue-purple?

Comment: It's the shade of purple you see in the linked screenshot. The deeper blue-purple is **Legendary**, and while some have reported being able to upgrade selected items to that level, those reports are in dispute.

Comment: This is great.  Can you ever learn a lower/equivalent recipe from REing, or is it only better recipes?

Comment: @MatthewRead Only improvements. You can't move back down the tree. However, often you'll just learn nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no cap, it is random.

For example [Skill Armoring 22](http://knotor.com/search?q=skill%20armoring%2022) has 4 levels in order to get each level you have to reverse engineer the lower level to get the higher level.

In your situation you are lucky. My friend spend an entire day and didn't get a single upgrade on a particular gem, next morning, first one.

Comment: Is the "Mastercraft" modification a legendary version?

Comment: At this moment I wouldn't be able to tell you.

Comment: As I understand it, "Mastercraft" is a critical success when crafting an artifact (which would otherwise be "advanced").  This is evidenced by having only three schematics on the linked page, with four results.

Comment: it's the devil that randomness is. I've had 2 streaks of over 20 failed attempts in a row, and between them, I successfully RE twice in a row. In average, I would say the chance is around 10% of a successful RE

Comment: @Rodolfo: The number I've seen speculated at is closer to 5%, but nobody has had the resources to do truly comprehensive testing on the subject just yet.

Comment: nah, that's wrong. 5% would be 1 in 20 chance, no way, it's much more frequent than that.  From my experience and those in my guild, it's like 1 in 10 chance.

Answer (score 0):

The second, more complicated system in [LessPop_MoreFizz's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/46063/6066) has changed with the *Shadow of Revan* expansion (Patch 3.0).  It still holds true for "old" schematics (skill levels 1-450), but there is a new and slightly simpler system for schematics over 450.  It reduces the number of Purple/Artifact items from 14 to 9, eliminating 5 items that added both tank and DPS secondary/tertiary stats to the base item.  (Note that it is still possible to add tank stats to a DPS base item and vice versa, but *both* types can never be added to any base item.)

Green/Premium items can be Reversed Engineered to learn Blue/Prototype items with increased Mainstat and Endurance:

- **Fervor** (additionally increases Crit and Accuracy)
- **Expert** (additionally increases Power and Surge)
- **Veracity** (additionally increase Defense and Shield)

Unlike the old system each of these prefixes is re-used for the highest tier, but it should not be confusing because it adds the same stats each time.

**Fervor** Blue/Prototype items can be RE'd to learn Purple/Artifact items with further increased Crit, Mainstat, and Endurance:

- **Fervor** (increases Accuracy further than the previous tier)
- **Supremacy** (removes the Accuracy added in the previous tier; increases Alacrity)
- **Endowment** (removes the Accuracy added in the previous tier; increases Surge)

**Expert** Blue/Prototype items can be RE'd to learn Purple/Artifact items with further increased Power, Mainstat, and Endurance:

- **Expert** (increases Surge further than the previous tier)
- **Hawkeye** (removes the Surge added in the previous tier; increases Accuracy)
- **Vehemence** (removes the Surge added in the previous tier; increases Alacrity)

**Veracity** Blue/Prototype items can be RE'd to learn Purple/Artifact items with further increased Defense, Mainstat, and Endurance:

- **Veracity** (increases Shield further than the previous tier)
- **Shielded** (removes the Shield added in the previous tier; increases Absorb)
- **Exactitude** (removes the Shield added in the previous tier; increases Accuracy)